# Flex update dataprovider after datagrid edited

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer, dataprovider

I have a `datagrid` in flex with an `itemrenderer` and a `dataprovider`.

The problem is when I edit a `datagrid`, the provider don't get updated with the edited value.

Here is my `datagrid`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="100%" borderColor="#FFFFFF" cornerRadius="0">
        <mx:Script>
            <![CDATA[
                import mx.core.Application;
                [Bindable]
                private var provider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {data:'1'},
                {data:'2"}]);
            ]]>
        </mx:Script>

<!-- Here is the data grid , the provider is groupeCollection, ihave set editable to true-->
            <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%" height="80%" 
                dataProvider="{provider}" x="0" editable="true" >
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="data" >
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:NumericStepper minimum="1" maximum="10000" />
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
                </mx:columns> 
            </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:Canvas>
```

Now after editing the cell ( `dataFiel="data"` ) and printing the `dataprovider`, nothing changes in it.

Comment: What version of Flex are you using?  Your code crashes when I try to run it in FB 4.7 with Flex 4.14.

Comment: Also, check the docs on bidirectional bindings.  That's my best guess for something that would help at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not used Flex 3 since long but can you once check that whether `ItemRenderer` supports `boolean` property `rendererIsEditor`? If yes then set it to `true` then your renderer will also work as editor.

EDIT: I tried your code now and there seems to be some compiler error with delcaration of items in `ArrayCollection`. You seem to mix `"` and `'` for items. I corrected it and now verified it in the below example which **works**. You can click the button to check before and after scenarios. I am pasting the complete code for your convenience just paste and run:

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                for(var i:int = 0; i<provider.length; i++) {
                    Alert.show(provider.getItemAt(i).data); 
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="100%" borderColor="#FFFFFF" cornerRadius="0">
            <mx:Script>
                <![CDATA[
                    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
                    import mx.core.Application;
                    [Bindable]
                    private var provider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                        {data:'1'},
                        {data:'2'}]);

                ]]>
            </mx:Script>

            <!-- Here is the data grid , the provider is groupeCollection, ihave set editable to true-->
            <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%" height="80%" 
                         dataProvider="{provider}" x="0" editable="true" >
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="data" >
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <mx:Component>
                                <mx:NumericStepper minimum="1" maximum="10000" />
                            </mx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
                </mx:columns> 
            </mx:DataGrid>
        </mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Button label="Check DP" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I added that, but still when i change the value in the cell, it didnt get updated in the provider... thanks for the time you give to my question.

Comment: Try this and let me know if you still face any problem. I tested this code in my FB and it works fine.

Comment: Hmmm indeed this example is working.... still i have the same problem when i change the code "in my app i am adding data to the datagrid and refresh it using `myGrid.dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE));` then when i try to edit, the changes dosen take place" anyway i'll accept your answer cause it works thanks @akhil_mittal :)

Comment: You do not need to dispatch collection change event as this part is done internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemEditor instead of itemRenderer, itemRenderer only show your values if you want edit the data at runtime we have set value manually by using

**data.propertyname = value;**

Try this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="100%" height="100%" borderColor="#FFFFFF" cornerRadius="0">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.core.Application;
            [Bindable]
            private var provider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {data:'1'},
                {data:'2'}]);
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <!-- Here is the data grid , the provider is groupeCollection, ihave set editable to true-->
        <mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" width="100%" height="80%" 
                     dataProvider="{provider}" x="0" editable="true" >
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="data" editorDataField="value">
                    <mx:itemEditor>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:NumericStepper minimum="1" maximum="10000" />
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemEditor>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns> 
        </mx:DataGrid>

        <mx:DataGrid  width="100%" height="80%" 
                     dataProvider="{provider}" x="0" editable="true" >
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="data" >
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:NumericStepper minimum="1" maximum="10000" />
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:DataGridColumn>
            </mx:columns> 
        </mx:DataGrid>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```